# Connection to Hive from python (3.9.7) via PysimpleGUI

Tags: python, hive, kerberos, pysimplegui

I am trying to connect to hive from python (script) and the connection is successful. However when I am passing the same conn str details via a GUI i created, I get the error :

> gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known which leads to TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not connect to host,port,auth_mech,kerb_serv_name,timeout,use_ssl").

The above executes fine when the values are passed directly instead of the conn str below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.util import as_pandas

layout_h = [
    [sg.Text('host',size=(10,1)),sg.Input(key='h')],
    [sg.Text('port',size=(10,1)),sg.Input(key='p')],
    [sg.Text('auth_mechanism',size=(10,1)),sg.Input(key='am')],
    [sg.Text('kerberos_service_name',size=(10,1)),sg.Input(key='ksn')],
    [sg.Text('timeout',size=(10,1)),sg.Input(key='t')],
    [sg.Text('use_ssl(True/False)',size=(10,1)),sg.Input(key='ssl')],
    [sg.Button('Test Connection'),sg.Button('Quit')],
    [sg.Text('Enter SQL',size=(10,1)),sg.Input(key='sqlquery1')],
    [sg.Button('Profile and Save'),sg.Button('Exit')]
]
sg.theme('dark grey 6')
window = sg.Window('Hive',layout_h)
event,values = window.read()
if event == 'Test Connection':
    hiv = connect(str(values['h'])+","+values['p']+","+str(values['am'])+","+str(values['ksn'])+","+values['t']+","+values['ssl'])

    imp_cursor = hiv.cursor()
    imp_cursor.execute(values['sqlquery1'])
    AV = as_pandas(imp_cursor)
```

P.S. I think I messed up the conn str(noobie trying to automate his tasks)

Comment: `connect(host='localhost', port=21050, database=None, timeout=None, use_ssl=False, ca_cert=None, auth_mechanism='NOSASL', user=None, password=None, kerberos_service_name='impala', use_ldap=None, ldap_user=None, ldap_password=None, use_kerberos=None, protocol=None, krb_host=None, use_http_transport=False, http_path='', auth_cookie_names=['impala.auth', 'hive.server2.auth'], retries=3)`, arguments not a string. Maybe a `**dict`, try to use kwargs as keys of Input elements. Maybe `int(port)` required.

Comment: Thank you @Jason Yang. It works when I pass the values in a single line, I think I will now, carefully concat the spec chars and try again via my GUI. All set now!